# Is rpg.stackexchange.com suffering from dissociative identity disorder or am I?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

In my profile I found the entry "recent names   2"  / "other names used in the last 90 days". What does that mean? I used 0 (zero) other names. Do I misunderstand something, or is there a bug?

Edit: I'm member for more than 90 days now, thus the entry is no longer in my profile.

Comment: Schizophrenia has nothing to do with being multiple people. You're looking for "Dissociative identity disorder". ;)

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir he could be referring to the site "seeing things that aren't there" which *is* a schizophrenia thing. :P

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir: OK, I changed it. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on clicking on the number of names, I saw your current name and "Anonymous," likely from when you first signed up and hadn't input a name yet.

Recent names is a new profile feature that allows you to see what aliases you've used in the past 90 days. For example, I used to go by my full name on Stack Exchange, but have since defaulted to using only my first name, as you see currently. This change, which I made in late November, is visible in my profile still.

So, to sum: you've had two names in the last 90 days, you haven't really misunderstood anything, nor is there a bug. This is just a new profile feature.

Comment: Thanks!  I had no idea on this one :)

Comment: +1 for "It's not a bug! It's a feature" :D

Comment: Thus in the first 90 days of membership there is always "recent names 2"? Well, it feels like some not optimal design. As I'm member for 89 days now, it should be solved automatically for me anyway. But +1 for the explanation!